# Using "Open Sans" font without Google Fonts in Emails

Tags: css, fonts

I have a doubt, the font open-sans is a safe font for use without google fonts?

I can't use an external link, how:

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

I need to use only the font-family declaration:

```
font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
```

Comment: Do you mean can you use it without having to link to the font?

Comment: Save the font  locally and link locally - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/ - Check this out - http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/open-sans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For email, you should only use a default font that will be present on a computer. The link below contains a list that you will be able to use.

http://blog.campaignmaster.co.uk/2013/01/10/email-101-email-safe-fonts/

Answer (score 0):

[Download Open Sans](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/open-sans) and change the `webfont` below to the open sans font name.

```
font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;

@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

Comment: Nice copy from CSS tricks ;)

Comment: Thanks, it took a lot of skill.

Comment: Guys, I'm sorry, I think I did not express myself right, I can't use web fonts, I need to do how would be like email marketing, for example

Comment: @MichelMakeiGefuni Custom font doesn't work in emails... You will only see the font appear on mobile devices. Other email clients will fall back to the next font in the stack.

Comment: Oh yeah, I've learned that the hard way rs rs
I know that Arial is a safe source to be used, but don't know if font Open sans is also a safe source for use

Comment: As far as I know, you have to code emails as if it's 1999 - likely by falling back to image renders of the text you need.

Comment: Thanks guys, apparently will not have the same way, I have to just use the classic email sources. lol